# VueJS communicate with parent container via v-for, supply both index and arguments

Tags: vue.js

I know I can communicate with the parent of a component like this:

```
<container>
    <child-component v-for="(thing, index) in things"
    :key="index"
    v-on:thingDidSomething="thingDidSomethingInParent(index)"  
    ></child-component>
</container>
```

However what if I want to supply arguments from the `thingDidSomething` method in the child:

```
v-on:thingDidSomething="thingDidSomethingInParent"
```

**and** supply the index (key). Can I access the key in the child component?

Comment: You could pass the index in as a prop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.$vnode.key` will give you the `key` value inside the child component. The `$vnode` property is not documented as part of the [public API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties) though. I think the safest way to do this would be something like this:

```
<child-component v-for="(thing, index) in things"
:key="index"
:index="index"
v-on:thingDidSomething="thingDidSomethingInParent"  
></child-component>
```

And the component

```
Vue.component("child-component",{
    props:["index"],
    methods:{
        emitThingDidSomething(){
            this.$emit('thingDidSomething', this.index, <other arguments>)
        }
    }
})
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jBJVwg?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Oh, is that the only way to do it, isn't there any simpler way? Can't you access the key directly in the child component somehow without passing it to props?

Comment: @user1506145 `this.$vnode.key` inside the child component will give you the key. Just be a little wary of using it because it is a Vue internal value.

Comment: @user1506145 I updated the answer and the example, but I still recommend passing it if you want it. Otherwise it's up to you! :)